# Null pointer Error while linking a .css file in a different folder

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a JavaFx OSGi project:

```
src
    main.java.ui.impl
        UI.java
    main.resources
        ui.css
```

I'm getting a null pointer whene I try to link up the Scene to the CSS file *ui.css* as follows:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("../../../ui.css").toExternalForm());
```

I've even tried to have the ui.css in the folder/ package *ui* directly above the package `impl` where **UI.java** is located, but still `null pointer`

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("../ui.css").toExternalForm());
```

It only works where all the files are placed in the same package:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("ui.css").toExternalForm());
```

What is the right way to go about this? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

---

---

**UPDATE**

Source repository on GitHub >>> [javafx-osgi-example-master](https://github.com/TryRevilo/javafx-osgi-example-master/archive/master.zip)

Be sure to first install Amdatu from the Eclipse marketplace

Answer (score 1):

Specify it relative to the class path, either by starting the path with a leading `/`, or by retrieving the resource from the `ClassLoader`:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/ui.css").toExternalForm());
```

or

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ui.css").toExternalForm());
```

The problem with your code as it stands is that you are not providing a valid resource name according to [this specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html). In particular:

> A resource is identified by a string consisting of a sequence of substrings, delimited by slashes (/), followed by a resource name. Each substring must be a valid Java identifier.

and, of course, `..` is not a valid Java identifier.

Comment: What will it be if it is one package up? `"/../ui.css"`?

Comment: It can't be one package up from the root of the classpath, by definition of "root".

Comment: Hi @James_D Thank you for the responses you gave to my question. Your suggestions should be working, but for some reason they won't work with my project. I updated my question with a link to the project source files on GitHub. [(javafx-osgi-example-master)](https://github.com/TryRevilo/javafx-osgi-example-master/archive/master.zip). I was hoping you could take a look and offer a suggestion. Thank you for your help so far